# Webpack where is that /main/ folder coming from?

Tags: angularjs, webpack

When I reload my first page, I get this error. (sorry I am pretty new at this)

```
Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'G:\Github\thaihome\app\main\app.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Error (native)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:305:1), <anonymous>:1:7)
```

I did a search for `main` in all files but cannot find `main` anywhere.

This is from my webpack:

```
  config.entry = {
    app: './app/app.js'
  };
```

Also as I understand, it compiles to `app.bundle.js` but where is that file located?

I wonder if the `main` is some default setting somewhere I have not looked?

Here is a screenshot of my folder structure:
[image: Folder Structure screenshot]

Comment: Can you share the full webpack config?

Comment: Of cause - right here:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/nhmes18e3k4rv5c/webpack.config.js

Comment: Are you using any reference to this file in any of your TS files? 'app.js'

Comment: What is TS?  (sorry im pretty new at this and google says its movie media)

Comment: typescript files :)

Comment: If you mean my js and json files then yes.  in package.json I have this line `"main": "app.js",` (wonder if that is it?)

Comment: Think so, can I have a look at the file.

Comment: Of cause:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcu7nvx0ed5yf5a/package.json

Comment: Also I took a quick screenshot of my folder structure for you
https://db.tt/nKP42OfEUQ

Comment: ARGH!!!!  @Thiagz I found the mistake....  in the webpack there is a comment like:  `/* whatever` and by mistake I removed one star, it should have been `/**` - once I fixed that everything worked :-D

Comment: Please update your answer - you deserve to get it for helping me :)

Comment: Oh cool, happy it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to the problem is to change /* comment to /**. Thanks @torbenrudgaard